# MFsidemenu disables scrolltotop table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, scroll, containers

I've successfully implemented MFSideMenu so that all the navigation works properly **except** scrollsToTop in the scroll views (Specifically in my TableViewControllers and one ViewController where the UIscrollview takes up the whole frame). scrollsToTop is not working, even though it is enabled in each TableView.

I know that it's the MFSideMenu causing the issue because I removed it from the project and the scrollsToTop is working fine then.

So here's how I call the MFSideMenu from the AppDelegate on launch:

```
//Instantiate the Side Menu and the center view
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTabBar"];

SideMenuViewController *leftSideMenuController = [[SideMenuViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *leftViewNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:leftSideMenuController];
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                containerWithCenterViewController:tabBarController
                                                leftMenuViewController:leftViewNavigationController
                                                rightMenuViewController:nil];

self.window.rootViewController = container;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

The TableViews I'm concerned with are embedded in NavigationControllers, which are embedded in the tabBarController referenced in the code above. And when I remove this block of code, the scrollsToTop works properly.

I think I need to adjust the container to include the TableViewControllers somehow. Any Ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer to my own question:**

The problem appears to be that I had the left menu inside a navigation controller. So I abandoned that, and made a storyboard layout for the menu controller to use instead. And in that storyboard layout I added a navigation bar to cover up the black space that normally appears in this version of MFSideMenu.

So the new window setup in AppDelegate is...

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UITabBarController *tbc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTabBar"];


//Then put get the left side menu controller, but inside of a navcontroller
SideMenuViewController *leftSideMenuController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SideMenu"];
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                containerWithCenterViewController:tbc
                                                leftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuController                                                    rightMenuViewController:nil];

self.window.rootViewController = container;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

The scrollview problem in the other UIViewController turned out to be an Autolayout issue.